# When does webflux validate the request body?

Tags: spring-webflux

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Resource
    WebClient webClient;


    @PostMapping
    public Mono<User> index(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<User> user){
        // I'm using webclient to call another service, just pass the mono object like this
        return this.getResponse(user);
    }

    private Mono<User> getResponse(Mono<User> user) {
        return webClient.post()
                .body(user,User.class)
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(User.class);
    }
}
```

In above scenario, I don't need to operate the request body. request body will not be validated.

How can I make webflux to validate the request body?

Comment: Why not just accept `User` object instead of reactive `Mono<User>`

Comment: this controller is generated by openapi generator, don't know how to configure.

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario, SpringMVC(not sure which componment will do) connot vaildate the Mono, so I cannot get a `webexchangebindexception`. the validation will occur when the Mono is subscribed which is also when webclient actually send the message.

before webclient actually sending message, validation will be done,`webexchangebindexception` will be catch by webclient. webclient will wrap this exception into `webclientrequestexception` by default. we can add our own exception handler to webclient so that we can just throw `webexchangebindexception` to our global exception handler.